# Create table dynamically using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I wanted to ask you if it is even possible to create tables dynamically in NodeJS using Sequelize.js. My goal is to create a simple TODO list where users can create a list (this list should be one table in my database). I have successfully established a connection with my database, created some simple models for my users. I want them to add tasks to their lists. I have also created a POST request route in NodeJS where the creation of the table should be done.

I found a code that can create a table (which it does) but I cannot add any items inside the list because the variable is local and I cannot use it anywhere in the code except the POST request in NodeJS. It still feels like static to me..

```
app.post('/todo/create', async(req: Request, res: Response): Promise <void> => {
   ....
   let Dummy = sequelize.define('dummy', {
       description: Sequelize.STRING
   });
   ....
}
```

For example, if I want to use it like I use my user model down below in login POST request

```
const existsUser = await User.findOne({where: {username: user}});
```

Any help or good direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want every user list to be in a different new table and the table name is dynamic - like based on user or anything else?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I would like to have a new table added everytime a user creates list.. and yes, the table name is dynamic.

Comment: But why do you want to do it? Any specific reason?

Comment: Because it seemed to me I couldn't create a list only in one table because if user creates some list, that list should belong to them. If there's another way, it would be nice to know.

Comment: Yes, should store it in different rows instead of tables. You can create an authentication system based on the unique user ID for each user and add data to the DB based on it. This way only the intended users will be able to get it. Or only for dev purpose you can take their emails and treat it as unique ID and you are good to go.

Comment: So this means I should create a general table called ''todo'', for example and every row I would create from now on in my ''todo'' would contain userID? What if I wanted to add multiple IDs so some users can share the same list? Should I stringify the array and place in database in userID?

Comment: Yes, you can do it just assign the user a role for read operations and they can read ToDo for any given user and you can create a group and add those users to that group and provide them data. FOr groups you should create a new table and add groups.